# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity

Tags: android, android-room, androidx

Recently I migrated from Android support library to AndroidX. While doing so I have upgraded the Room DB gradle dependency from 1.0.0 to 2.2.5.

We haven't changed anything in the table or db schema and so the version of the db was not incremented.

Now for some of the user, I am getting exception while trying to clear the tables.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you’ve changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:154)
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:135)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:142)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
```

The only change in the schema file is the import statement changes from support library version to AndroidX version.